# Undefined reference to GLIBC_2.15

Tags: c++, python-2.7, libc

I have a project which shows following error in the linking:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so: undefined reference to '__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 which libc6 (GLIBC_2.19) is installed on.
I cannot understand the issue and also found no solution.